# Chrome/Safari ignoring my reset rules?

Tags: css, safari, google-chrome

[link text](http://tinyurl.com/bt5n4c)

In Safari/Chrome it has extra spacing on the left/top of ol's, blockquotes and other elements.

I can't isolate this, however when I look in the web inspector in Safari, its picking up a margin-left: of 26px on some elements. I have not specified any such rules, so is this a bug in Web inspector?

Can someone enlighten me as to why these exta spacing problems are occurring? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That margin-left:26px is the "computed style" of your styling margin-left:2em. Hence why it's under Computed Style section in Safari's Web Inspector. 
So if you change your margin-left to some other values the computed-style pixel value will also change too.

Anyway there are indeed extra padding! And it's caused by the user agent stylesheet (-webkit-padding-start:40px). Reset this style by setting padding:0 on your ol and any others elements you want.

A good way to prevent this problem from happening again and develop without worry is to reset your css. A basic reset would be:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer jason. It has indeed done the trick.
I have used that universal selector many times in the past, but for some reason I chose to use the Eric Meyers reset rules this time, which don't go quite as universal as that. Ah well, a lesson learned.

Comment: I did not know about the universal selector/reset and it indeed does work.  What a great tip!